# After deleting note, the user does not receive the notification

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to achieve that, if the user removes a remark, they receive a notification about the deleted remark. But so far in my app it doesn´t work. Nothing happens if the user removes the remark.

Below I posted the code of the class where I want to implement the notification. After clicking on button "Delete",the user should receive a notification about the change in the database.

I tried:

1. Use youtube to make notification, but they do it without channel
2. Change position of code about notification
3. Create function with notification code

... nothing of this has worked ...

```
public class EditDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "EditDataActivity";

    private String CHANNEL_ID = "ID";
    private int notifId = 1000;

    private Button btnSave,btnDelete;
    private EditText editable_item;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private String selectedName;
    private int selectedID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_data_layout);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        editable_item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

        //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
        selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

        //now get the name we passed as an extra
        selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

        //set the text to show the current selected name
        editable_item.setText(selectedName);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String item = editable_item.getText().toString();
                if(!item.equals("")){
                    mDatabaseHelper.updateName(item,selectedID,selectedName);
                }else{
                    toastMessage("You must enter a name");
                }
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDatabaseHelper.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
                editable_item.setText("");

                Intent intent = new Intent(EditDataActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(EditDataActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

                createNotificationChannel();

                final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(EditDataActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("NOTIFTITLE")
                        .setContentText("TEXT")
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);


                toastMessage("removed from database");
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Name of the channel";
            String description = "Description of the channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forget some code. Add this line to your code

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(id, b.build());
```

Full code

```
 btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabaseHelper.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
            editable_item.setText("");

            Intent intent = new Intent(EditDataActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(EditDataActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

            createNotificationChannel();

            final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(EditDataActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("NOTIFTITLE")
                    .setContentText("TEXT")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
            //ADD THIS LINES 
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
            toastMessage("removed from database");
        }
    });
```

You can use random integer for id, or single id if you want update notification or cancel it.